# Local/session storage of Office Add-in

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I developed an Microsoft Office Add-in for Outlook which forwards e-mails including some specific user-managed content. The add-in is hosted as a static website on GCP according to [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/publish/publish-add-in-vs-code). Everything works fine, but I need to know where data is transferred to and how I can prove it.

I need to prove that the Add-in **only reads (GET)** from GCP (the HTML, CSS & JavaScript files) and storages them locally (temporarily). This should be the case, because when I load the Add-in and then take down the GCP server, the Add-in including all functionalities still works for +/- 15 minutes.

How can I best prove that my Add-in reads the static files from GCP and stores them locally? I cannot find any Microsoft documentation on this.

Comment: Does GCP mean Google Cloud Platform? I don't see it mentioned in the article that you linked to. Could you clarify?

Comment: Yes, sorry, GCP means Google Cloud Platform. I'm using GCP instead of Azure.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on how you need to prove that the add-in read the static files from GCP and stored them locally? Are you looking for manual validation or automation?

Comment: I needed to prove it by an overview that only GET requests are being made and no data is being send to the server. I confirmed this by now, in GCP you have a logs explorer where you can monitor your App Engine. In here, I can see that only GET requests are being made.

Comment: It seems the GCP logs are sufficient here, which is the right approach. Are you still trying to prove the local storage of the static files read from GCP? You can simply fire up a regular browser and connect it to a static file on GCP, take down the server, and see if the page works for +/- 15 minutes.

Comment: Exactly, GCP logs are sufficient. I also tried to prove the storage of static files read from GCP and I applied exactly the same approach as you mention, which is sufficient for my case. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your add-in acts like a web site which is loaded locally and cached temporarily depending om the MIME header property values.

The Office cache folder is described in the [Clear the Office cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache) article. Don't forget about the browser cache folder.